# CSS written after pseudo-element not working

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm working on Ruby-on-Rails 3.2.1. I've following DOM structure.

**UPDATE:** removed the `</img>` tag as mentioned by [Gaby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128165/gaby-aka-g-petrioli). Problem still persists.

```
<div class="frame">
        <img src='SOME_PATH' class="frame-image">
</div>​
```

And following CSS

```
.frame { position:relative;border:1px solid #CCC;border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px; }
.frame:before
{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    border:2px solid #F2F2F2;
    height:100%;width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
img.frame-image     /* IT WON't BE APPLIED?! */
{
    min-width:30px;min-height:30px;
    max-width:200px;max-height:200px;
}​
```

The problem I'm facing is, CSS applied to `img.frame-image` is not working/not getting applied. I tried on Chrome 18 and FireFox 12. I don't see the style in Chrome's element inspector or in FireBug. It is also not getting overridden by any other CSS.

For demo I tried to create [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/2CeFN/) for this. It works there!

But surprisingly when I write `img.frame-image` CSS above `.frame:before` CSS, it works!!

```
.frame { position:relative;border:1px solid #CCC;border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px; }
img.frame-image        /* NOW IT WILL BE APPLIED */
{
    min-width:30px;min-height:30px;
    max-width:200px;max-height:200px;
}​
.frame:before
{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    border:2px solid #F2F2F2;
    height:100%;width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Any idea why is it happening? is it framework (RoR) related issue or CSS semantics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all remove the `</img>` as [that is invalid](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html#img-tags)..

> **Tag omission**
>
> The `img` element is a void element. An img element must have a start tag **but must not have** an end tag.

Make sure that the CSS is loaded (*and not using a cached version*).
Also make sure that there is no script that might be removing/altering your classes.

(*i also hope the comment in the CSS are just for stack overflow as they are invalid*)

---

**Update**

Firebug was showing a weird space at the beginning of the rule so i run

```
var txt = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].cssText;
console.log(0, ':', txt[0],':', txt.charCodeAt(0) );
```

and got `8203` as the charCode ...

This is the zero-width-space character. You need to remove it as it is being used as part of the selector (*and thus fails*).

---

To see the change live, try running

```
var txt = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].cssText;
var fixedRule = txt.substring(1);

document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(3);
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(fixedRule, 3);
```

from firebug console, and you will see that it will be fixed .. (*the only thing the script does, is to remove the wrong rule and reinsert it after removing the first character*)

Comment: yeah... I just put those comments here for better understanding. I'll update it.

Comment: Removed that `</img>` tag. But still the problem persists.

Comment: @bongs, any scripts that might be removing /toggling classes ?

Comment: The site is in very early stage and there is no script interference there. You see just by writing `img.frame-image` above `.frame:before` makes it work!!! Is it CSS bug? Are you able to reproduce the issue or is it just me facing it? btw +1 for tag omission suggestion.

Comment: @Bongs, there should be no conflict since they apply to different elements.. there seems to be no syntax errors in the example.. I cannot reproduce the issue.. But it should not be a RoR issue either as it has nothing to do with client-side issues.. Could you put it live somewhere, so we can see it in action ?

Comment: Give me some time. I'll let you know.

Comment: @Bongs, you have a 0-width space at the start of your rule. You need to remove that because it causes the rule to fail (*as it is being used as part of the selector*). Not sure how it gets there. It might be the minimizer you use..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11671/discussion-between-bongs-and-gaby-aka-g-petrioli)

Answer (score -2):

try changing the name from frame-image to frameImage or something? remove the hyphen?